# Account of Priori knowledge in Critique of Reason

Tags: epistemology, kant

As I understand, a priori statements are propositions that are conceived independently of one's experience.

However, the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy states that

> The sensible world, or the world of appearances, is constructed by the human mind from a combination of sensory matter that we receive passively and a priori forms that are supplied by our cognitive faculties. We can have a priori knowledge only about aspects of the sensible world that reflect the a priori forms supplied by our cognitive faculties. In Kant’s words, “we can cognize of things a priori only what we ourselves have put into them” (Bxviii). So according to the Critique, a priori knowledge is possible only if and to the extent that the sensible world itself depends on the way the human mind structures its experience.

I gather from this that our mind and our experience work jointly to know the world. As an example, our mind might provide us with two priori propositions:

1) Our world is necessarily causal.
2) Our world isn't necessarily causal.

Drawing from our experience, we will conclude that the proposition 1 is the priori that describes our world. (Edit) Hence in such a manner, our mental cognition works together with our experience to know the intelligible world.

Is this inference from the passage accurate?

Comment: What "a priori" means to Kant is subtle, SEP specifically discusses how ["independent of experience"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/apriori/#WhaMeaIndPhrIndExp) does not mean what one might think. Despite his declarations that "*knowledge that is absolutely independent of all experience*" he also says that "*concepts without intuitions are empty*", i.e. experience is needed at least to grasp the concepts if not to justify the claims. But I doubt that Kant would endorse "more or less attuned to our world" gradations where justification is concerned. It is either a priori, or it isn't.

Comment: @Conifold Does the edit now makes sense us?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is unfortunately incorrect.

When Kant speaks of *a priori* knowledge he means either:

1. Propositions which can be known **absolutely independently of experience**, ex. Pythagorean theorem.
2. Propositions which are stipulated prior to experience and make it possible as **transcendental conditions of possibility**, ex. the law of gravitational attraction in Newtonian physics.

There are propositions, such as theorems of mathematics (including the aforementioned Pythagorean theorem), which play both roles, i.e. (1) and (2). Kant says that the method of mathematics is *construction* (this is quite controversial) - which is fully independent of affection by an object and thus of experience and therefore *a priori* in the sense of (1) - but furthermore, he says, mathematics constitutes a necessary condition of spatio-temporal experience, so it's *a priori* in the sense of (2), because the possibility of performing certain constructions is presupposed by measurement of spatio-temporal magnitudes. This is what the *Transcendental Deduction* of the *Transcendental Aesthetic* establishes.

Consider gravitational attraction F = GmM * R^-2. This proposition is obviously a generalization from experience and that's how Newton himself saw it. However, Kant challenges Newton and says that there's also a sense in which it is *a priori* as, without forces that act immediately at a distance, you couldn't define absolute simultaneity. So the very existence of forces like the gravitational force in Newtonian physics, although it is confirmed only *a posteriori*, makes some central features of time, presupposed by all experience (in Newtonian physics), possible. Gravitational attraction (and other laws of nature), then, is *a priori* only in the sense of (2) or, as Kant sometimes says, ***impurely** a priori*.

The proposition you mentioned, i.e. the law of causality, Kant says, is a most general feature of all scientific theories, i.e. a **transcendental law of nature** (cf. his proof of the *Analogies of Experience*). These laws, which then are *in concreto* fulfilled as, for example, Newtonian laws of motion, follow from time having certain objective characteristics which, Kant says, can be known *a priori* in the sense of (1). However, Kant is wrong about this, because the geometry of actual-space time, we know thanks to XIX-th century physicists, mathematicians and philosopers and ultimately due to Einstein, is also known due to experience and measurement. This doesn't ultimately challenge the notion of a transcendental law of nature as Kant conceives it, but shows that these are also quite *impure*, although *a priori*.

It's important to note that for Kant the paradigm case of experience, as he highlights in the *Preface* to the B edition of the *Critique of Pure Reason*, is **experiment** - which necessarily involves **quantitative measurement**.